# Como acessar Virtual Machine (feita em qemu-kvm)

Tags: linux

Tenho um servidor Linux Centos7, sem interface gráfica. Usando Qemu-KVM consegui instalar dentro dele uma máquina virtual com windows2008server.
Usei o seguinte comando pra criar a maquina virtual:

```
 virt-install --name=windows --ram=3096 --vcpus=1 --cdrom=/opt/win2008server.iso --os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k8 --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics=spice --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/win.dsk,size=15
```

A máquina virtual foi criada com sucesso, e está rodando. 
Porém agora não sei como fazer pra acessa-la remotamente. Tentei o virt-viewer de uma estação Ubuntu, até acessa, mas na hora de formar a tela, dá um erro de falta de uma biblioteca libspice. Já instalei tais bibliotecas, mas nada.
Alguém tem alguma dica de como acessar (pode ser via Windows ou Linux) essa máquina virtual que está nesse servidor sem interface gráfica? Que software devo usar?
Notem que no comando de criação da vm, tem a opção graphics, onde escolhi spice.
Eu poderia tentar outra opção para o parâmetro graphics?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Galera, já consegui... bastou mudar a opção --graphics para "vnc".
Com isso consegui acessar de outra estação windows usando o virt-viewer.